# SPACYR: lemmatization may not work properly in model 'en_core_web_sm'

Tags: r, spacy

I am unsure why I am getting this warning:

> lemmatization may not work properly in model 'en_core_web_sm'

I have a custom install of Spacy as per instructions on the [Install Spacy](https://spacy.io/usage) webpage:

```
conda install -c conda-forge spacy
conda install -c conda-forge spacy-lookups-data
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

and initialise in R as follows:

```
spacy_initialize(condaenv = "C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/", model = 'en_core_web_sm') #refresh_settings = TRUE to switch python environment
```

Lemmatisation seems to be working, and I know it is a warning not an error, but I wouldn't mind understanding I am getting it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the authors of `spacyr` aim to print this warning for every non-English model, cf [this comment](https://github.com/quanteda/spacyr/blob/fc4b91cb32c122b1b3260bdb825b92bd61ee8abd/R/spacy_parse.R#L21)

> @param lemma logical; include lemmatized tokens in the output
>   (lemmatization may not work properly for non-English models)

and the code [here](https://github.com/quanteda/spacyr/blob/fc4b91cb32c122b1b3260bdb825b92bd61ee8abd/R/spacy_parse.R#L108):

```
 if (lemma) {
        model <- spacyr_pyget("model")
        dt[, "lemma" := get_attrs(spacy_out, "lemma_", TRUE)]
        if (substr(model, 0, 2) != "en"){
            warning("lemmatization may not work properly in model '", model, "'")
        }
    }
```

So it actually shouldn't hit for `en_core_web_sm`, if I understand it correctly. It could be a bug in this warning code snippet.

From spaCy's perspective - we are aware that lemmatization is (obviously) not always perfect, and there are definitely ways to improve. But in general I think `en_core_web_sm` will produce reasonable results.